# Timer for Slideshow does nothing

Tags: javascript

Sorry for that short and meaningless title, but it really is the only one that really describes my problem.

I want (or have to) script a slideshow which (if a checkbox is checked and a time is given) automatically switches the focus on another image.
I already have everything but the automation and am currently working on it.

I thought that comparing the current time with a target time (currentTime + user-input seconds (in Integer)) every 1000 millisecs would be the best way to do it.
However, I don't get why, but it's not working. The calculated target time seems to be correct, since I get a correct difference of the pre-calculated date.getTime() and the calculated one.

I would be very thankful if you could help me.

Here's the JS:

```
var checkbox_checked;

function timerfn() {
    if (checkbox_checked === null || checkbox_checked === false) {
        checkbox_checked = true;
        var targetTime = new Date();
        alert(targetTime.getTime());
        var target_sec = targetTime.getSeconds() + dauerSwitch;
        targetTime.setSeconds(target_sec);
        alert(targetTime.getTime());

        // update currentTime every 1 Seconds (1000 Milliseconds)
        setInterval(function () {
            var current_time = Date.now();

            if (targetTime.getTime() == current_time) {
                gallery("zur");
            }
        }, 1000);
    } else {
        checkbox_checked = false;
    }
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="timer" name="timer" onClick="timerfn()">
    <input type="text" id="textbox" name="timerParam"
        placeholder="Seconds between slides" value=""
        onBlur="boxConv()"> //boxConv just converts the String to an Integer. It also checks if it's only numbers
</form>
```

Comment: I am getting a javascript error on `var current_time = new Date.now();` but `var current_time = Date.now();` works for me.

Comment: D'oh, you're right. But the function unfortunately still doesn't work for me.

Comment: A tip: use console.log() instead of alert(). Look for the console by pressing F12 in Chrome or F12 in Firefox if you have the Firebug addon installed.

Comment: `if (targetTime.getTime() == current_time)` is a really bad idea. The chances that your `setInterval` will fire at exactly the right time for that equality to be true is probably very small. Try using `<` or `<=` instead so you can tell if it's later than the target time and do whatever `gallery` is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Thats how i would do it with a little help of jquery ($). I moved the inline code into JS event listener and used the user input as parameter for the interval to make it work.

```
$(function () {
    var intervalTime = 1000,
        counter = 1,
        interval;

    $("#textbox").on("blur", function () {
        var inputValue = $(this).val();

        try {
            //parses the user input into a integer
            intervalTime = parseInt(inputValue, 10) * 1000;
        } catch (e) {
            //could not parse input
        }
    });

    $("#timer").on("click", function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                //gallery("zur");

                //fills the test output
                $("#testOutput").val(counter);
                counter++;

            }, intervalTime); //intervall time is given in milliseconds
        } else {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });    
});
```

And here the link to a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Yeuh/2/

Comment: jQuery was not tagged in the question so be wary that this answer may be down voted.

Comment: I thankfully accept every answer that's useful, no downvote by me.